# Cisco ASA 5512 port forwarding

Tags: cisco, asa

I Can't open port on ASA 5512 with ASDM. I tried dynamic, PAT and Static configurations in nat. But without success.

All traffic goes normally, but i cant direct it to inside network host . 
I am confused that it has global rule which denies all ip traff. But i cant delete them.

My configuration and some variations with nat:

[first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20QYW.png)

[second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHffg.png)

Comment: Flagging as off-topic since this is a networking question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use like the following... Obviously, change the IP Address, and Interfaces names on the NAT statement...

object network dmz-webserver1

host 192.168.1.2

nat (dmz,outside) static interface service tcp www www